# django template not rendering folder images

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

here is my code bellow.
views.py

```
def galerry(request):
result = request.GET.get('folder')
print(result)

imageList = []
directory = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
for file in os.listdir(directory+"images/"):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png"): 
        src = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        imageList.append(src)
        print(filename)


json_object1 = json.dumps(imageList)
print(type(json_object1))
response = json.loads(json_object1)
print(type(response))
print("json conversion", json_object1)
return render(request, 
              "galerry.html", 
              context={'json_object1': response})
```

The loop worked fine i got all the files in the folder using print function
but the image link seems not found in djando template.

galerry.html file

```
{% for item in json_object1  %}
 <img src="{{item}}" alt="test" height="200">
 {% endfor %}
```

settings

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),  "static_root")
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "gallery/static_cdn/")
```

im getting
Not Found: /Users/joejoe/Desktop/Gallery/gallery/static_cdn/05.jpeg
[15/Jan/2022 04:57:05] "GET /Users/joejoe/Desktop/Gallery/gallery/static_cdn/01.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1828

thanks will appreciate your help

Comment: You missing `/` in `os.listdir(directory+"/images/")`

Comment: there is a strange detail: in the error message the missing file is "05.jpeg" but the GET request is for "01.jpg" - is that a typo here in the Post only? Where do you store the images? ist the path in the error message the path you expect? But the start of the Path on windows should be something like "C:/ ...."  so how did you set BASE_DIR?

Comment: Another hint: the html better should point to a /media/..../pic.jpeg and your server should translate that in a system path. See django docs handling media files.

Comment: the print function gave this result 01.jpeg
02.jpeg
03.jpeg
04.jpeg
05.jpeg
["/Users/joejoe/Desktop/Gallery/gallery/static_cdn/01.jpeg", "/Users/joejoe/Desktop/Gallery/gallery/static_cdn/02.jpeg",  ..etc. it successfully loop through all the files in the folder . the problem is rendering all the images in gallery.html i get this error in the terminal [20/Jan/2022 05:10:26] "GET /galerry/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3201
Not Found: /Users/joejoe/Desktop/Gallery/gallery/static_cdn/03.jpeg and [20/Jan/2022 05:10:26] "GET /Users/joejoe/Desktop/Gallery/gallery/static_cdn/05.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1828